Oracle SQL Loader for CLOB data type
Currently I am using oracleSQL Loader utility to load the data into the database. My CTL file is shown below. Here the column "LM_CAUTION_NOTE" data type is CLOB in the table. When I execute the SQL Loader facing error as "ORA-39777：data saves are not allowed when loading lob columns"
Here I could not combine or merge the input files as it is generated from external system. Any other way to achieve this?
LOAD DATA CHARACTERSET UTF8 
    INFILE "E:\sample1.txt"
    INFILE "E:\sample2.txt"
    
APPEND
INTO TABLE FBNK_CUST_CAUTION_NOTE_M1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' -- SEPARATOR
ENCLOSED BY '~%' -- ENCLOSED
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    code CHAR(240),
    LM_CAUTION_NOTE CHAR(7000)
    
)


It looks like that ought to just work. It's probably off-topic here really, but maybe include the log file to see what it's really doing and if there are other useful errors. And which database and client version you are using. It kind of sounds like bug 20254971 but that's supposedly about direct-path loads. Still, maybe try with a single infile and see if that works?

There are several bugs related to this error (2906977.1, 20254971). All of them are talking about "direct load".
You can try to work around it by disabling the direct load: add DIRECT=FALSE to the command line of the sql loader.
